# How to enable parts of code with external files .plist or .xcconfig

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, fastlane

I have a project that I'm using the fastlane toolchain to build.

I have multiple deployment targets (hockey app, test flight, app store) - and for each deployment I'm interested in disabling and enabling certain features.

For example - when i'm doing an alpha build with an enterprise cert to hockeyapp i want to disable flurry analytics.

When i'm doing a beta build I want to change the app-id and/or change the flurry key

I currently have everything working in fastlane with a variety of `sed` commands to search and replace files etc.

That being said, I'm sure there is a better way.

I know in Obj-c i can `#ifdef` against certain build environment flags to enable / disable parts of code.  What is the best way to go about this in swift.

Do I use some sort of custom `.plist` file or `.xcconfig` setting to tell the app what to do/use or is there a different way?

The things i'm interested in are

- Disabling portions of code ( ignore a certain function in a specific config)
- Changing values used in code aka `API_KEY` or something like that

Answer (score 3):

You can still use something similar to `#ifdef` preprocessor in swift, and you can combine it with `.xcconfig` which can be used to specify various variables. Your scripts can generate the values that will go into the `.xcconfig` vars.

The basic setup would be:

1. Create a `.xcconfig` file and associate it with your desired build configurations (in project settings -> info).
2. Add variables to the `.xcconfig`. For example, if you want to activate ALPHA build you can do something like this: `IS_ALPHA_BUILD=-D ALPHA`. Notice the `-D` which is necessary here. Your scripts can leave the variables empty if you want the flag turned off.
3. In the build settings for your target, under "Swift Complier - Custom Flags" - > "Other Swift Flags" add the flag based on the `.xcconfig` file variables: `${IS_ALPHA_BUILD}`. If the `.xcconfig` is setup correctly you should see its content of the variable once you're done editing the variable.
4. Use the flags in your code:

   ```
   #if ALPHA
       print("alpha")
   #else
       print("not alpha")
   #endif
   ```

I hope this helps, or that it will at least give you an idea for the best approach suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the optional code in separate files that implement it using extensions.  You can then enable/disable files using the file properties in the project Navigator.

I'm doing this even for a single application for which I have 3 targets in the project : full IOS version (paid),  limited IOS version (free) and apple TV version.

I also use the same technique to enable/disable stubs for whole classes that are used in several places but only actually work in one of the targets.

Comment: So - thats great if you want to use the GUI but i'm using fastlane which is a build toolchain that allows you to do everything from command line

Comment: Ho sorry, didn't know what fastlane was, thought it was just another framework.  Can't help with command line stuff (been running away from them for years)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar conceptual problem. I want to use FDD and than use a mechanism to disable features as per need. I am going to experiment with pList. 
My initial idea is to declare all features in plist and give them boolean values. Thus, if a feature needs to be enabled, I will only enable it in plist.

On the programming side, I am planning to write all features as extensions for parent data type with enclosing conditional statements. Therefore from perspective of controller , my code efforts will be reduced to just calling the behavior/ function.

I hope it made some sense,  I will probably rewrite the answer sooner than later